# How to implement an Integer DCT with matlab?

Tags: matlab, dct

I need to do integer DCT over a picture, but after I searched the Internet for a long time, I still can't get the method. That's why I'm here to ask for help.
I'm looking forward that I can be provided with the description of the method of integer DCT, or better, the matlab source code. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: First result from Googling "discrete cosine transform matlab" is https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html Does this help?

Comment: Thank  you. But it doesn't work because what I need is integer DCT instead of normal DCT. Thank you again! ;)

Comment: An answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621167/dct-using-integer-only) question provides a link to MATLAB code and a description of the algorithm.